# Remove \`u2022` unicode special character from python list

Tags: python

I want to remove `\u2022` from the `dList` but i am getting same list again

```
dList = [u'\u2022 Slim fit',
 u'\u2022 Barrel cuffs with two buttons',
 u'\u2022 One button on sleeve placket',
 u'\u2022 Turndown collar',
 u'Washing Care: ',
 u'\u2022 Machine wash low in cold water',
 u'\u2022 Medium iron',
 u'\u2022 Do not bleach',
 u'\u2022 Hang to dry',
 u'\u2022 Do not tumble dry',
 u'\u2022 Wash separately',
 u'Model\'s measurements: Chest 34", Waist 30", Hips 32"',
 u'Height: 175cm.',
 u'He is wearing a N. Tyler Size 15.5.',
 u'Please note: ',
 u'Although we do our best to make sure that the colours shown on our website are accurate, actual colours may vary due to monitor/display/resolution.',
 u'Dark Blue Checks',
 u'100% Cotton , European Fabric']

[i.replace("\u2022"," ") for i in dList]

Output: 

[u'\u2022 Slim fit',
 u'\u2022 Barrel cuffs with two buttons',
 u'\u2022 One button on sleeve placket',
 u'\u2022 Turndown collar',
 u'Washing Care: ',
 u'\u2022 Machine wash low in cold water',
 u'\u2022 Medium iron',
 u'\u2022 Do not bleach',
 u'\u2022 Hang to dry',
 u'\u2022 Do not tumble dry',
 u'\u2022 Wash separately',
 u'Model\'s measurements: Chest 34", Waist 30", Hips 32"',
 u'Height: 175cm.',
 u'He is wearing a N. Tyler Size 15.5.',
 u'Please note: ',
 u'Although we do our best to make sure that the colours shown on our website are accurate, actual colours may vary due to monitor/display/resolution.',
 u'Dark Blue Checks',
 u'100% Cotton , European Fabric']
```

Also tried :

```
import re

[re.sub("\u2022","",i) for i in dList]
```

But no luck....can someone help me please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`unicode`s are `unicode`s and `str`s are `str`s.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

```
[i.replace(u"\u2022", u" ") for i in dList]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x.encode('ascii','ignore') for x in dList]
```

Should do the trick.